# Listar dados duplicados

Tags: mysql

Estou sofrendo com dados duplicados no banco e preciso listá-los para verificá-los e excluí-los. Considero como dados duplicados quando o valor e a data coincide, como no exemplo abaixo, os valores A e C são duplicados.

```
A: 2017-08-10 - 10.00
B: 2017-08-10 - 10.01
C: 2017-08-10 - 10.00
D: 2017-08-11 - 10.00
```

Através de uma consulta preciso que apenas A e C apareçam.

```
A: 2017-08-10 - 10.00
C: 2017-08-10 - 10.00
```

Tentei desta forma, mas sem sucesso:

```
SELECT data, valor FROM tabela
WHERE data > '2017-04-17'
HAVING COUNT(valor) > 1
```

Infelizmente desta forma os dados vem agrupados. Tentei adicionar `GROUP BY  primary_key` sem sucesso.

Obs.: MySQL 5.7

Comment: Se você quiser somente listar os duplicados pode fazer assim: `SELECT data, valor, count(*) as quantidade FROM tabela WHERE data > '2017-04-17' GROUP BY data, valor HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: @LaércioLopes realmente é uma alternativa. Trás os dados corretos, mas não trás os dados conforme necessito. Não deixa de ser uma boa ideia. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Veja se é isso:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5209/4/0)

```
select 
    * 
from 
    table1 a
where 
    ( data, valor ) in 
        ( select 
             data, valor 
          from table1 
              group by data, valor 
          having count(*) > 1 )
```

[Execute no SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5209/4/0)

Comment: De fato deu certo. Precisei adaptar algumas coisas e funcionou de boa